# In php what is more efficient n-1 < x OR n <= x

Tags: php

What is more efficient

```
if ($n-1 < $x)
```

or

```
if ($n <= $x)
```

Anyone know?

Comment: It is probably better to use `<=`, since that is what it is there for. Also, I am guessing that it is slightly more efficient, but not enough to matter.

Comment: Again, although `<=` reads "less than or equal to", it does NOT mean the computer performs two separate operations to achieve this.  See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430706/comparison-efficiency/1430713#1430713

Comment: What is with all the micro-optimization questions today?

Comment: Micro-optimizations are beneficial if and only if your application is a benchmark for micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Negligible difference, but `if ($n <= $x)` is much clearer.

Comment: Why is this the most upvoted? this didn't even answer the question correctly, the second one is more efficient.

Comment: The point of my answer is that it doesn't freaking matter AT ALL and you should strongly prefer the clearer syntax.  I guess 10 people agreed.

Comment: I agree with "just pick the clearer syntax", but disagree with the assertion that that is always the same one of the options.  Which one is clearer depends on the application.  If you're reserving the first, or last, element of some array, $n-1 < $x might be clearer.

Answer (score 6):

Probably `($n <= $x)` since there's one less operation (no subtraction). However, this is only equivalent for integers and the difference is very likely insignificant.

Comment: If the language you're using doesn't automatically pick the more efficient instructions, then you should log a missed-optimization bug against your language's implementation.

Comment: @Bernd Seriously?... I doubt the subtraction could easily be optimized way, especially given that in C, for two ints `n - 1 < x` is different from `n <= x` (the integer can wrap around).

Comment: Yikes!  I didn't think of overflow.  Then again, two things: the OP is about PHP, and in C the behaviour on overflow is undefined.  So a (C) compiler could legitimately transform `n-1<x` into `n<=x`, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be significant speed gain but later seems more **readable** to me. The first one has an extra subtraction part too.

Answer (score 3):

In the first instance you're performing two operations (subtract then compare) whereas in the second you're performing just one (compare). I think it's safe to say the second is more performant. Regardless, the first form is very nonstandard and I don't know why it would ever be used as a substitute for the second.

Answer (score 3):

Neither. PHP has no enforced implementation saying weather it's bytecode, interpreted directly from the AST, or compiled to machine code. In fact, there are a billion different implementations and the main one probably changes all the time just like the rest of the language and API.

Even at the assembly level in x86, there is no difference between the two operations. Proof:

x < y

```
cmp eax, y
jb its_true
```

x <= y

```
cmp eax, y
jbe its_true
```

`JBE` is a synonym to something like `JC` IIRC, which just checks a single flag. Both of these conditional branches simply check if a flag is set or not.

The only real way these operations could effect speed is you could overload both less than/greater than operators and equality, and even then the speed difference should be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a high-level scripting language, it's not a matter of processor operations to perform that action. More time will be spent in parsing the code, validating variable types and managing variables memory and many other things.

Even if there's no practical difference, I guess the second will be faster since the language expression is simpler.

The term $n-1 is in a section more complex to understand that <=. The math operator has only a few options (>, <, <=, ==, >=, !=, ...), but the term $n-1 requires a more complex analysis because it has to be split by the minus sign at first, and then analyzed both parts (which could also be a function call, a constant, a variable, another complex expression, ...)