# Is one of them quicker: if (!foo < bar) if (foo > bar)?

Tags: javascript, performance

Out of curiosity. I check whether some string is longer than a maximum specified length:

```
var name = "This Is a Name";
if (!name.length >= 10)
{
    //valid length
}
else
{
    alert("Too long");
}
```

Is this any better / faster (?):

```
if (name.length <= 10)
```

I remember that in some languages it's better to write the negation first so is it even betterer (yip, I just wrote that) like so (?):

```
if (10 >= name.length)
```

I know that 10 is overlapping in the code - don't mind that. I just want to know if there is any performance / best practice on this.

Comment: 1. Are you really doing this check so often that performance matters? 2. Even if performance mattered, I would guess these checks are pretty much the same, and I would recommend caution with the !name.length syntax (operator precedence). 3. If performance is really that important, I'd recommend setting up a benchmark

Comment: Try it at http://jsperf.com/ ;)

Comment: No not at all - I don't care about the performance. I'm just curious what's "best"

Comment: Have you tried timing the two versions? I suspect that if there is a difference it will depend on your hardware and the browser you are using.

Comment: `!name.length >= 10` is not the same as `!(name.length >= 10)`.  The `!` operator binds tighter than `>=`, making it `(!name.length) >= 10`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430706/comparison-efficiency/1430713#1430713

Comment: If performance isn't an issue, then "what's best" is what is easiest for someone else to read and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is out of your hands, the interpreter will do whatever it deems right with this. Javascript interpreters might be so advanced nowadays they will optimize this, but more likely those interpreters themselves are compiled with a compiler that will have optimized the translation itself so it was even out of the hands of the person that wrote the interpreter.

So really, if you want a language where you want to control this kind of behaviour, you need asm. Not even in (optimized) C do you really control this.

The only thing you can say with certainty is that `n.length > 9` could be marginally faster because it contains *less characters* so it will be parsed quicker. We're talking nanoseconds, maybe even picoseconds there, though.

Comment: And the network transmission of the single `!` character will probably take longer than parsing it or the actual execution of a NOT operation on the CPU.

Comment: I didn't think of advanced JS compilers built into browsers like Firefox's late TraceMonkey. Of course these all have different behaviors and IE's JS renderer might interpret everything differently.

Answer (score 3):

I almost always use `<` and `<=` instead of `>` or `>=`. I find that always having the smaller value on the left (when the test succeeds) is quicker to mentally parse. It also makes range tests:

```
if (0 <= a && a < 10) …
```

read more like the mathematical equivalent 0 ≤ *a* < 10.

Performance-wise, I'd be surprised if there was any measurable difference.

Comment: I totally agree. Also note that, on the lowest level there is no difference between < and >. The machine code instruction is the same, just the order of the "parameters" (registers) is changed.

Comment: @noah1989: Thanks for the comment. I should note that there is a difference at the machine level between JGE and JLE. However, which one the compiler chooses will probably have more to do with which values end up in which registers prior to the test than whether `<=` or `>=` is used in the code.

Comment: You're right of course. I was refering to the CMP instruction before the jump, though.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not actually the bottleneck of your application, I'd recommend the most **readable**, not the most performant code - even if there was a slight difference in performance, which I doubt there really is in your case.

In your case, the most easily understandable code piece as far as I am concerned, would be:

```
if (name.length <= 10)
```

If you're really intent on getting the most performance out of your code, you would have to write some tests; because speaking generically about this is not possible in most cases, e.g. nearly every JavaScript implementation already will behave slightly different.

Also make sure to check up on "Premature Optimization", e.g. in the wikipedia article on [Program optimization (section "When to optimize")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Answer (score 1):

Let me just comment on your last example: I am fairly sure that your `if(10 >= name.length)` convention was started in the era of bad C compiler warnings as an effort to avoid errors of the `if(pointer = NULL) { error(); } else { i = *pointer; }` type, since the reversed version would make the typo cause a compiler error. This is still surprisingly relevant in jslint-less JavaScript, but I don't think it can affect non-equality comparisons.

For the rest of it, I'm also firmly in the "no difference" camp, even though I haven't experimented, I just can't think of plausible causes where the order would make a performance difference.